# Rails 3: Ensure before_save callback is called after others

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Is there a way to ensure that a given before_save callback is executed after all other before_save callbacks in ActiveRecord short of actually ordering them so in the code?

I'm writing an external library that includes some before_save functionality but in order to be effective it really needs to be called after all others. I can get around it but it involves giving up dirty attributes which I really don't want to!

-- edit --

I didn't realise in this that dirty attributes are maintained after the save of the model. So @page.attribute_was will still work after the `yield` in an `around_save`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could make the callback you want executed last an `around_save` callback. Check out the [list of available](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.9/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#available-callbacks) callbacks and see if you can simply use a different callback "bucket" for some of your callbacks to ensure they are executed in the desired order.

If you still end up with multiple `before_save` callbacks and need one to trigger last, you may want to create custom callbacks, like maybe `define_model_callbacks :split_save`, registering your regular `before_save` callbacks as `before_split_save` callbacks, the one you want executed last as a `after_split_save` callback, and then just a single `before_save` callback that runs those two groups of callbacks (`run_callbacks :split_save`). See [`ActiveModel::Callbacks`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Callbacks.html) for more on how to do this.

Comment: Thanks Carl. I had tried using an `around_save` and putting my code before the `yield`, however some `before_save`s were still being called after it. I couldn't work it out. I'll definitely have a look at ActiveModel::Callbacks tomorrow and report back.

Comment: @JonHope yeah, I've never actually used `around_save`. Looking at the docs it appears it *should* always fire after before_save callbacks, but "around" callbacks work a bit different so I may have misunderstood. Might want to try making all the callbacks except the one you want executed last into `after_validation` callbacks, leaving the last one a `before_save`. Custom callbacks will work too, but `after_validation` might save you effort.

Comment: Thanks Carl. Unfortunately I can't use custom callbacks because I need the gem to be a drop-in solution, I can't make people change their callback code. My train of thought is to find the array of callbacks and manually add mine to the end before the object gets saved. Is this a goer?

Answer (score 1):

So this was to get around giving up dirty attributes by using ordered `before_<type>` callbacks instead of `after_<type>` callbacks, since dirty attributes `changes` get wiped after saving.

It turns out, however, that the `changes` are still accessible in `after_<type>` callbacks.

I only worked this out after trawling through [Vestal Versions](http://github.com/laserlemon/vestal_versions) code to see how they did it.

Facepalm.

I'm accepting Carl's answer because it's a pretty complete answer to the rather badly presented question.